# Mocha variable initialized, but is null when used

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to test auth protected route. I get the token in the before() hook and I print it in the console - it's fine, the token exists in the response. I assign it to a variable, but when I send it in the next text case, it's null.

```
const assert = require('assert'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    app = require('../app'),
    superagent = require('superagent')

describe('Testing the api/product POST route', function() {

    let token = null;
    const credentials = {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'test'
    }

    before(function() {
        superagent
            .post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/login')
            .send(credentials) // sends a JSON post body
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return
                }
                token = res.body.token
            });
    }),

    it('should return 422 status when you send an empty product object', function() {
        request(app)
            .post('/api/products')
            .send({})
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                assert.equal(1, 1)
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some trial-and-error work, I figured it out. The problem was that the call made in the `before()` function didn't finish before I used it in the test below. So basically, `token` was still null. Here is the fixed code:

```
    const assert = require('assert'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    app = require('../app'),
    superagent = require('superagent')

    describe('Testing the api/product POST route', function() {

    let token = null;
    const credentials = {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'test'
    }

    before(async function() {
        const res = await superagent
            .post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/login')
            .send(credentials) // sends a JSON post body
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            token = res.body.token
    }),

    it('should return 422 status when you send an empty product object', function() {
        request(app)
            .post('/api/products')
            .send({})
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            .then((res) => {
                assert.equal(1, 1)
            })
    })
})
```